# Strange Ports opened on my Iphone?

Tags: network, mac

I've run NMAP several times on my home network in my campaign of learning the basics of network security.

So far all my devices except my PC have been Iphones/Chromebooks so nothing has been found in the way of open ports and so on (Apart from a few clear ones i.e 443/80).

However, runnining Nmap today I've found these ports randomly opened on the macaddress + Ip address associated with an iphone at home.

- 1062/tcp  filtered veracity
- 1088/tcp  filtered cplscrambler-al
- 1105/tcp  filtered ftranhc
- 1217/tcp  filtered hpss-ndapi
- 2002/tcp     filtered globe
- 2006/tcp  filtered
- invokator 2323/tcp filtered 3d-nfsd
- 4443/tcp  filtered pharos
- 5102/tcp  filtered admeng
- 6101/tcp  filtered backupexec
- 6346/tcp  filtered gnutella
- 7103/tcp  filtered unknown
- 18101/tcp filtered unknown
- 26214/tcp filtered unknown
- 44443/tcp filtered coldfusion-auth

Highly confused and wondering if anyone recognizes these ports for Iphone. Off the bat I see things like Gnutella and coldfusion, to name a few. Highly boggling.

I've had funky behaviour recently . A random port has opened up on my router out of the blue 49152/tcp. Only seeing this after this has happened. Before getting conspiratorial I wonder if anyone here has a sound rationale for this

Comment: "Filtered" means they are actually *not* open though…?

Comment: Right like a Firewall Rule or a network issue might stop traffic going through these ports. Do you know why IOS configures these ports ? If NMAP is able to detect these ports as filtered they must be enabled for some purpose right?

Comment: Okay appreciated thanks for redirecting me

Comment: This was initially cross-posted & is now a direct duplicate of [Strange Ports opened on my Iphone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431089/strange-ports-opened-on-my-iphone)